# What type of cat is the שונרא of חד גדיא?

Tags: translation, animals, passover-seder-hagada, aramaic

In "חד גדיא," the cat eats the goat. What type of cat was this that was big enough to be eating a goat?

My understanding from reading various articles is that this song was composed around the 1500s in Europe though there is no consensus on that.

Comment: Maybe the piyyut is allegorical. See [here](http://www.tehilim.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%93-%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9-%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98-%D7%97%D7%93-%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%90-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%A4%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%95-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%90/%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D) for an explanation.

Comment: note - we are talking about a kid (baby goat) not an adult goat

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Y5ZhtO8.jpg

Comment: Maybe the kind of lion that Dovid Hamelech fought.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I don't think there is any physical description of any of the animals, and I've understood this poem as allegorical. I think you should extract some material from the link as post it as an answer.

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/J2UZEx

Comment: Maybe it's a plural (in meaning, though grammatically singular)?

Comment: Why do you think it was a unique large cat? Perhaps it was a baby goat?

Comment: If you think that's hard to wrap your mind around, then know that there are also centuries-old versions of the song that include a *mouse* - either eating the goat, or eating one of the last creatures in the chain - after the bigger ones.

Comment: A character cat

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_wildcat#Hunting_and_diet From time to time, it also preys on small carnivores like martens, European polecat, stoat, and least weasel (Mustela nivalis), as well as fawns of red deer (Cervus elaphus), roe deer (Capreolus capreolus), and chamois (Rupicapra rupicapra).

Answer (score 0):

The entire piyyut is to be taken allegorically, with the little goad (chad gadya) representing Israel, the father Hashem, and the two zuzim the  two stone tablets (the Luchot).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_Gadya):

> As with any work of verse, Chad Gadya is open to interpretation. According to some modern Jewish commentators, what appears to be a light-hearted song may be symbolic. One interpretation is that Chad Gadya is about the different nations that have conquered the Land of Israel: The kid symbolizes the Jewish people, the cat, Assyria; the dog, Babylon; the stick, Persia; the fire, Macedonia; the water, Roman Empire; the ox, the Saracens; the slaughterer, the Crusaders; the angel of death, the Turks. At the end, God returns to send the Jews back to Israel. The recurring refrain of 'two zuzim' is a reference to the two stone tablets given to Moses on Mount Sinai (or refer to Moses and Aaron). Apparently this interpretation was first widely published in pamphlet published in 1731 in Leipzig by Philip Nicodemus Lebrecht. This interpretation has become quite popular, with many variations of which oppressor is represented by which character in the song.

The entire article there is quite interesting; noting how the author's Aramaic skills were lacking and how there is terrible grammar used throughout the song (and has been corrected in many texts).

In a more literal sense, which is what you asked, there are many cats large enough to eat goat kids, notably the [bobcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobcat), [lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion), [tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger), [mountain lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar), etc. And nowhere does the song say that the cat ate the goat whole. I'm sure even my family's own pet cats could eat a goat kid if they were hungry enough.

Comment: If the cat is a lion, then what kind of dog ate it?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Again, allegory. If one reads the piyyut literally you're going to be left quite confused or chuckle at how stupid it is. And again, the dog doesn't have to swallow the lion whole. [African Wild Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_wild_dog), [Dingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingo), [Gray Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_wolf), and [Coyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote).

Comment: Lions, tigers and bears .. Oh My!

Comment: @DoubleAA The dog only bit the cat.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure metaphorical.

Rabbi Benjamin David Rabinowitz in his work ["Ephod Bad"](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Nirtzah%2C_Chad_Gadya.2?vhe=Pesach_Haggadah&lang=bi&with=Ephod%20Bad&lang2=en) on the Haggadah explains that this is an reference to the Talmudic statement that a dog recognises its master, while a cat does not [(Horayot 13a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Horayot.13a.23?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Rabbi Rabinowitz then goes on to explain what "Then came a cat and ate the kid" means.

> Despite G-d's redemption of Israel from Egypt, Amalek came up with a plan to get around G-d's protection of Israel by attacking the weakest of them.
> Yet Israel was even worse. **The Israelites refused to recognize their Master in Heaven and cast doubt on G-d, and they acted like a cat who does not know its own master.** (emphasis mine)

Amalek, the Ephod Bad says, is a reference to the dog, while the Israelites were a reference to the cat.

The [Minchat Ani](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Nirtzah%2C_Chad_Gadya.1?vhe=Pesach_Haggadah&lang=bi&with=Minchat%20Ani&lang2=en) writes that the goat symbolises Esav.

> The goat is a symbol of Esau while the lamb is a symbol of Jacob